# Instances in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, instance

I'm wondering about instances in UIScrollView.

I checked what is happening for the instances in UIScrollView just by writing a easy code.

Here is the code.
**UIViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomScrollView.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

CustomScrollView *sv1, *sv2;

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    int height = self.view.frame.size.height;

    sv1 = (CustomScrollView*)[[CustomScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, height/2)];
    sv1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:sv1];
    [sv1 setIntegerWithNum:1];

    sv2 = (CustomScrollView*)[[CustomScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, height/2, 320, height/2)];
    sv2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:sv2];
    [sv2 setIntegerWithNum:2];

    int returnVal1 = [sv1 getInteger];
    int returnVal2 = [sv2 getInteger];

    NSLog(@"Sv1:%d, Sv2:%d", returnVal1, returnVal2);
}
```

**CustomScrollView.m**

```
#import "CustomScrollView.h"

int number;
@implementation CustomScrollView

-(void)setIntegerWithNum:(int)num {
    number = num;
}
-(int)getInteger {
    return number;
}
```

By this, I see the values in the output area.
I thought it will be "Sv1:1, Sv2:2" because the numbers are set as 1 and 2, respectively. 
But I got an output like "Sv1:2, Sv2:2"

What happened here?

Comment: set `number` as @property in `CustomScrollView.h`

Answer (score 0):

You have only one variable of type `int` in your `CustomScrollView.h` that your setting with your setter `setIntegerWithNum` and then you are returning the value of "`int` number" with your getter `getInteger`. essentially with your setter, you are setting your "number" variable twice. The second time you set it with 2. so the variable `number` then holds 2, overwriting the previous value 1.

Therefore when you use the getter for the `NSLog`, you are returning the same value twice.

I would follow @Akhilrajtr's advice. simply set number as a property of type `int`. Then you will correctly return each object's property. That is, each individual objects `int` property for sv1 and sv2.

You can do this with `@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger *number;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

set `number` as @property in `CustomScrollView.h` by

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) int number;
```

then in `ViewController`

```
sv1 = (CustomScrollView*)[[CustomScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, height/2)];
sv1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:sv1];
[sv1 setNumber:1];

sv2 = (CustomScrollView*)[[CustomScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, height/2, 320, height/2)];
sv2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:sv2];
[sv2 setNumber:2];

int returnVal1 = [sv1 number];
int returnVal2 = [sv2 number];

NSLog(@"Sv1:%d, Sv2:%d", returnVal1, returnVal2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you declared

```
int number;
```

not as an instance variable or property.
 You can do this in two ways

1.

```
@interface CustomScrollView(){
int number;
}
@end
```

2.

```
@interface CustomScrollView()
@property(nonatomic)int number;

@end
```